# How to restore tensor summary to a variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained my network and saved the final weights as summaries like this:

```
# ...
weights_summaries.append(tf.summary.tensor_summary('out-weights', weights['out'])) 
# ... write summary
```

Now I want to use my classifier. I'm trying to load weights from summary:

```
for e in tf.train.summary_iterator(summary_file):
    for v in e.summary.value:
        # ...
        # found the node
        elif v.node_name == 'out-weights':
            weights['out'] = tf.Variable(v.tensor)
            # it doesn't work!
            weights['out'] = tf.Variable.from_proto(v)
            # assert!
            weights['out'] = tf.Variable.from_proto(v.tensor)
            # assert!
            weights['out'] = tf.Variable(tf.Tensor.from_proto(v.tensor))
            # Tensor.from_proto is not defined!
```

So, how should I load the weights? I know about the "global" model saver but I would prefer saving only the data I need.

Thanks in advance,
Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution:

```
def tensor_summary_value_to_variable(value):
    fb = numpy.frombuffer(v.tensor.tensor_content, dtype = numpy.float32)
    shape = []
    for d in v.tensor.tensor_shape.dim:
        shape.append(d.size)
    fb = fb.reshape(shape)
    var = tf.Variable(fb)
    return var
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a subset of the model, I would suggest you use the `var_list` parameter in the `tf.train.Saver` [constructor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/state_ops/saving_and_restoring_variables).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It would be great if it was possible to restore weights from summaries though,